# Why does pressing shift and scrolling forward fire the mouse click event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to increment a value in a listview control using the scroll wheel. I want the value to increment by 10 when the shift key is held while scrolling. Holding the shift key and scrolling forward fires the listviews mouseclick event. Scrolling backward does not. The click event shows the left mouse button clicked. Is this behavior by design?

Comment: Can you use e.handled = true; to block the mouse click event?

Comment: Yes, that will work as the wheel event fires before the click (thanks). I would still like to know what is the reason behind this event firing.

Comment: It seems my mousewheel event declares e as MouseEventArgs, and does not have e.handled. Do you have a code example of how to use it?

Comment: I have submitted an answer for that issue. I personally do not know why a click event is fired using mouse weel + shift. I would also like to know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `((HandledMouseEventArgs)e).Handled = true;` in the MouseEventArgs to prevent the selection issue.